# What's the order of the records after calling getall() method on a custom setting?

Tags: customsetting, map, list

I've got a `getall().values()` on a custom setting, but the values retrieved doesn't seem to be ordered by the record's name. Why? Do I have to use only the `getall()` and then run a loop and order it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sets in Apex are [unordered collection](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_collections_sets.htm). If you want to iterate over custom settings in alphabetic order, try this:

```
Map<String, Custom_Setting__c> cs = Custom_Setting__c.getAll();
List<String> keys = new List<String>(cs.keySet());
keys.sort();

for (String key : keys) {
    Custom_Setting__c = cs.get(key);
    ...
}
```